# Does an open source font exist supporting primarily unicode's symbols / dingbats?

Tags: fonts, icons, open-source, unicode

Does a font exist supporting primarily unicode's symbols, pictograms, dingbats blocks?

http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf
... and more

On Windows, there is "segoei ui symbol" that supports nearly all of them in the windows 8 version.  But I was looking for an open source one (or with some similar license) because I want to use it as web font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) supports a number of pictographs and is free for any use.

Comment: seems great. very thank you... do you know some good font editor supporting unicode ? i want to drop off unnecessary symbols because embedding 2mb on a web page... well... isn't a good idea!

Comment: My normal go-to is FontForge, but I'm not sure it supports anything past U+10FFFF.

Comment: Symbola seems to be the only font that satisfies the criteria. Another free font that contains such symbols and pictographs is [Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/), but it has a much more limited repertoire